# SAS Visual Analytics show only TOP (10, 20, 30, ...) rows based on slicer

Tags: sas, report

I'm working on SAS Version Stable 2023.10. In my report I have a page with a crosstab and I would like to either only show Top 50 results / rows or in best case create a slicer to enable the report users to define how many rows they can see. Maybe based on the ROW NUMBERS option that is build in. I was not able to find something on the web so far. Maybe someone has an idea or could point me into the right direction. Thanks in advance.

This is what I tried so far

- added ROW NUMBERS to crosstab, these are now visible in the report
- played around with RANK